# Numeric tags on dash icons

Tags: 23.10

Some of the dash icons have numeric tags (a white number in a green circle) at their upper right. This can happen whether the associated app is open currently in single or multiple occurances or not open at all.

What do the numbers signify?

[image: image showing icons with & without tags]

Answer (score 2):

The numbers are the count of outstanding notifications for each app.